# Cant solve this : Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I know this is a stupid question and I know what is wrong with my code but can't figure out WHERE is the error.

```
function saveEvent($event_id,$old_category_id,$old_site_id,$old_user_id,$old_name,$old_description,$old_standby_start,$old_standby_end,$old_standby_reason,$old_standby_conclusion,$category_id,$site_id,$user_id,$name,$description,$standby_start_date,$standby_start_time,$standby_end_date,$standby_end_time,$standby_reason,$standby_conclusion)
{
  $standby_start = $standby_start_date." ".$standby_start_time.":00";
  $standby_end = $standby_end_date." ".$standby_end_time.":00";

// create new pdo object
$pdo = dbConnect();

try
{
    $pdo->beginTransaction();

    $req = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO t_events_changes
                                 (ec_event_id,ec_old_category,ec_new_category,
                                  ec_old_site,ec_new_site,ec_old_author,ec_new_author,ec_timestamp,
                                  ec_old_name,ec_new_name,ec_old_description,ec_new_description,
                                  ec_old_standby_start,ec_new_standby_start,ec_old_standby_end,
                                  ec_new_standby_end,ec_old_standby_reason,ec_new_standby_reason,
                                  ec_old_standby_conclusion,ec_new_standby_conclusion)
                          VALUES (:event_id,:old_category_id,:new_category_id,
                                  :old_site_id,:new_site_id,:old_author_id,:new_author_id,NOW(),
                                  :old_name,:new_name,:old_description,:new_description,
                                  :old_standby_start,:new_standby_start:old_standby_end,
                                  :new_standby_end,:old_standby_reason,:new_standby_reason,
                                  :old_standby_conclusion,:new_standby_conclusion);");

    $req->execute(array(
        ':event_id'                 =>  $event_id,
        ':old_category_id'          =>  $old_category_id,
        ':new_category_id'          =>  $category_id,
        ':old_site_id'              =>  $old_site_id,
        ':new_site_id'              =>  $site_id,
        ':old_author_id'            =>  $old_user_id,
        ':new_author_id'            =>  $user_id,
        ':old_name'                 =>  $old_name,
        ':new_name'                 =>  $name,
        ':old_description'          =>  $old_description,
        ':new_description'          =>  $description,
        ':old_standby_start'        =>  $old_standby_start,
        ':new_standby_start'        =>  $standby_start,
        ':old_standby_end'          =>  $old_standby_end,
        ':new_standby_end'          =>  $standby_end,
        ':old_standby_reason'       =>  $old_standby_reason,
        ':new_standby_reason'       =>  $standby_reason,
        ':old_standby_conclusion'   =>  $old_standby_conclusion,
        ':new_standby_conclusion'   =>  $standby_conclusion
    ));

    $req2 = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE t_events
                      SET t_categories_category_id = :category_id,
                          t_sites_site_id = :site_id,
                          t_users_user_id = :user_id,
                          e_last_change = NOW(),
                          e_name = :name,
                          e_description = :description,
                          e_standby_start = :standby_start,
                          e_standby_end = :standby_end,
                          e_standby_reason = :standby_reason,
                          e_standby_conclusion = :standby_conclusion
                      WHERE event_id = :event_id");

    $req2->bindParam(':category_id',$category_id,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $req2->bindParam(':site_id',$site_id,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $req2->bindParam(':user_id',$user_id,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $req2->bindParam(':name',$name,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $req2->bindParam(':description',$description,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $req2->bindParam(':standby_start',$standby_start,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $req2->bindParam(':standby_end',$standby_end,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $req2->bindParam(':standby_reason',$standby_reason,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $req2->bindParam(':standby_conclusion',$standby_conclusion,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $req2->bindParam(':event_id',$event_id,PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $pdo->commit();

    echo 'Update complete';
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    // rollback the transaction
    $pdo->rollback();

    // display error message and datas
    echo 'Tout ne s\'est pas bien passé, voir les erreurs ci-dessous<br />';
    echo 'Erreur : '.$e->getMessage().'<br />';
    echo 'N° : '.$e->getCode();

    // exit the catch to avoid the next errors
    exit();
}
}
```

Maybe I am blind, maybe the error is coming from something else but I am reading my code for an hour now and still don't understand where is the problem

Comment: start by counting everything.

Comment: `... :new_standby_start:old_standby_end ...`

Comment: oh ^ lovely and a nice catch @Rizier123 OP's not using this I take it http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: question's off-topic

Comment: that's what happens when one doesn't make their code "breath". It just leaves room for making errors and not spot "what's different".

Comment: Fred -ii- Dude, If I come to post something about syntax error and I know this is something like this, I already try to make my code "breath", one parameter per line and everything.

Don't be that salty, I know this happend to everybody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing Comma (,) in this line. Due to which bound variables were not matching.

```
 $req = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO t_events_changes ....
              Values (... :new_standby_start:old_standby_end, ... )");
                                           ^ here missing comma
```

Change it to,

```
:new_standby_start,:old_standby_end,
```

Comment: Holy Sh*t, thank you, that's what I was looking for. Too much time looking at the code, couldn't make the difference at the end...

Comment: If you think this answer helped you. Please mark it as correct answer. So, that other people do not do this type of mistake Mr @Anaon